# Options passed to babel with article class and not with beamer

Tags: beamer, babel, key-value, class-options

In this example using article class options `arabic-ma` and `provide=*` are passed to babel, but when changing  to beamer class options  are not passed to babel. Is there an explanation?

```
\documentclass[arabic-ma,provide=*]{article}%{beamer}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}


\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}

\today

%\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/815

Comment: As workaround you can use `\PassOptionsToPackage{arabic-ma,provide=*}{babel}`